# Decomposition of the AdhocHost compound module into simple modules

Tags: omnet++

In order to analyze and understand the behavior of the AdhocHost compound module, especially in the use of its signals, it has better to extract its simple modules from its complex module(s).
Does anyone have documentation of the break down of this complex module into simple modules?
In [the AdhocHost compound module documentation](https://doc.omnetpp.org/inet/api-current/neddoc/inet.node.inet.AdhocHost.html), there is some details about the AdhocHost module.
Thanks

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by _extract its simple components_? Actually, AdhosHost consists of compound modules that consist of simple modules.

Comment: I meant simple components in question, simple modules. I changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a simulation in Qtenv where an Adhoc host is present and explore its internals by double clicking various modules. Whenever you reach a point where you cannot go deeper, that's a simple module. You can do the same in the left side property inspector where you can display the components in a tree view.

Comment: How to find the signals of the simple modules of it?

Comment: Looking into NED files?